# How do we send json to the controller & iterate based on key in java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Below is my JSON:

```
{
    "key1" : "10.5",
    "key2" : "20.5",
    "key3" : "10.5",
    "key4" : "20.5",
    "key5" : "10.5"
}
```

I want to send this Json to the controller class while calling post service & I want to iterate json based on the key in the class. How do we receive the json in our class & How do we iterate.

I did the below:

```
@PostMapping("/api/v1/save")
public String save_commodities_user_predict_data(@RequestBody String jsonData) {

    System.out.println("jsonData:"+jsonData); 

}
```

In the console, I am getting below output:

```
jsonData:{
    "key1" : "10.5",
    "key2" : "20.5",
    "key3" : "10.5",
    "key4" : "20.5",
    "key5" : "10.5"
}
```

Now, How do I iterate jsonData and get the value based on the key in my java class?

Please clarify.

Comment: Well, you have a Json string and need to parse it, e.g. using a library like Jackson or Gson. If you don't know what keys can be sent then you'd want to parse the Json into a `Map<String, Object>` and iterate over that. You'd probably not have to call the parser yourself though, Spring MVC should be able to handle it if your parameter type matches the input, i.e. you could try `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> jsonData`.

Comment: Hey Mustapha - thanks for the explanation. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your parameter type to `Map<String, String>` and iterate over the map. If there's a reason you can't do that, you'll have to parse the string into a json.

```
@PostMapping("/api/v1/save")
public String save_commodities_user_predict_data(@RequestBody Map<String, String> jsonData) {

    for (Entry<String,String> pair : jsonData.entrySet()){
        //iterate over the pairs
        System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" "+pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Aditya - thanks for the explanation. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change a little bit

```
public class MyClass{

    private String key;
    private Integer value;
}


@PostMapping("/api/v1/save")
public String save_commodities_user_predict_data(@RequestBody List<MyClass> myClass) {

    myClass.forEach( c -> {
        System.out.println(c.getKey() + c.getValue()); 

    });
}
```

Json:

```
{[{ 
    "key": "key1",
    "value": 10.0
},
{ 
    "key": "key2",
    "value": 10.0
}]}
```

Comment: Hey cvdr - Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you can you the libraries GSON ou Jackson.
First create the Beans that haves the same properties as your Json, for example:

{"name":"John", "age":"24"}

```
class Person {
 private String name;
 private String age;

//getters and setters 
}
```

But you can find more information in the libraries documentation